# $n^2 \le n^{\log_2 (n)}$?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function

during a lesson on complexity calculus (algorithms) my professor, by ordering functions, showed that $ n^2 \le n^{\log_2 (n)} $, but it is not clear to me why.
If I take for example $ n = 2 $ I would have that $ 4 \le 2 $, that doesn't make sense, perhaps the result only makes sense to tend from $n$ to infinity? or how is it possible?

(I know it's a stupid question but I don't know how to get out of it)

Comment: you are correct it holds after some n, which is $4$

Comment: If you consider $n^k \leq n^{\log_2 (n)}$, take the $\log_2$ of both sides and you will see than the equality/ineaquality holds when $n\geq 2^k$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Clear now, thanks!

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi thank you!

Comment: Consider first at the equality $n^k = n^{\log_2 (n)}$. Take logarithms (any base), simplify. The solution is immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If n > 1, then $n^x <= n^y$ if and only if x ≤ y. In this case, whenever $2 ≤ \log_2(n)$ which is the case whenever n ≥ 4. For 1 < n < 4 it is not true.

If n = 1 then the exponent doesn't matter, so for n = 1 the statement is true.

For 0 < n < 1 (assuming we are talking about real numbers as well) it is the opposite, $n^x <= n^y$ if and only if x ≥ y. In this case, whenever $2 ≥ \log_2(n)$ or n ≤ 4.

So the statement is true if 0 < n ≤ 1, or n ≥ 4.